# How to persist Entity object which contains another Entity Objects to the database?

Tags: database, jakarta-ee, netbeans, entity

I have a problem with my function which is supposed to save data to database, function creates a new object which includes other objects. I am able to save and fetch objects which contain only primitive data types and Strings to Database , so the database and system works in this case. I am using JavaEE and EntityManager (persist).
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a cascade type on the parent entity. Have a look on the Java EE tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#bnbqm)

see the principal below

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="customer")
    public Set<Order> getOrders() { 
        return orders; 
    }
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Order {
    @OneToOne
    Customer customer;
    ...
}
```